# Windows Push notification via pushsharp fails after app reinstall - Device Subscription Expired

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, pushsharp, wns

**PushSharp version** : Version 2.2.1
**Issue Description**

- I am using pushsharp to send push notifications to windows phone app 8.1.
- I installed the app on a windows phone and got a channel URI. Using the same channel URI the push notification worked for me.
- Then I uninstalled and installed the app again on the windows phone. This gave me an updated Channel URI.
- Using the updated channel URI, the push notification fails with the error:"Device Subscription Expired:
  PushSharp.Windows.WindowsPushService -> <>"
- Kindly let me know is there something that I am doing wrong because of which the notification fails after reinstalling the app
  (i.e. with new channel URI).

**Sample Code**

```
push.RegisterWindowsService(new WindowsPushChannelSettings("package name", "package security identifier", "client secret")); push.QueueNotification(new WindowsToastNotification() .AsToastText01("This is a test notification") .ForChannelUri("https://db5.notify.windows.com/?token=AwYAAADhaxGQuJHxAGCdCOJa+kyrZ012wjF19Zm+VfriKZVxKqM3Dt4kQz9t6EllMZHgiA4oE1uvij2wdiTwItmp7UUnGoAPp3hc9FnLkJqpckt1xQAux/wez++MVGaty0QKRNk="));
```

**Exception**

> "Device Subscription Expired: PushSharp.Windows.WindowsPushService -> new channel URI"
>   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue. The device token was getting url decoded while transmitting from angular UI to pushsharp app. Encoding again helped to gain the actual channel URI.

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(DeviceToken);
```